# Flash of unstyled content (FOUC) in Firefox only

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, fouc

I'm not seeing this issue in any other browser that I've tested - IE, Chrome, Opera - but whenever I load a page from the server, I'm seeing a flash of unstyled content before the CSS is applied only in Firefox.

You can check this url in your Firefox browser, last version 59:
https://regalaunpuzzle.es/puzzles-personalizados

Comment: Have you tried increasing when your cache expires? By the looks of things it expires on load https://imgur.com/a/yXaLT

Comment: Hi. Have you found fix for this problem?
Now I have the same problem as you and no one advice helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the reason of FOUC in FF was the presence of iframe on page.
If I removing iframe from markup then FOUC disappears.

But I need iframe for my own hacking reasons so I changed this

```
<iframe name="hidden-iframe" style="display: none;position:absolute;"></iframe>
```

into this

```
<script>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
    let nBody = document.querySelector('body')
    let nIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    nIframe.setAttribute('name', "hidden-iframe");
    nIframe.style.display = 'none';
    nIframe.style.position = 'absolute';
    nBody.appendChild(nIframe);
  });
</script>
```

I've added this inline JS right in template just for readability: in my case this code runs once per page.
I know that it's dirty hack, so you can add this code in separated JS-file.

The problem was in Firefox Quantum v65.

---

I see that your page has iframe too, so this way can help.

Comment: Thanks for this, this fixed the problem for me. Here's the bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1420362

Answer (score -1):

Set the body visibility as hidden, then in a separate JavaScript file add an onload function to make it visible again. What we are essentially doing is slowing down the page a bit to load the styles before the document gets loaded.

What I did was set a class to body `<body class="hidden">`, then is css `.hidden {visibility: hidden}`, then is javascript:

```
const body = document.querySelector(".hidden");


window.onload = () => {

   body.removeAttribute("class");

}
```